# Why won't my SQL table creation work in Codio?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to complete my homework but am getting an error message saying that the table I'm creating doesn't match what is expected to be input.  Here is what the table is supposed to contain:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| room_num  | int(4) unsigned | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| course_id | int(3) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The code I am entering to try and achieve this is:

```
CREATE TABLE college.classrooms (

id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

room_num INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,

course_id INT(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (id),

FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES college.courses(id)

) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

My school uses Codio and it auto checks the table to see if it's correct and that is the error message I'm getting:

> [Error]: Create a 'classrooms' table with the requested structure. Reset the database and try again

What am I missing from my code to make this work? I've already created the table it is referencing (courses).

Comment: The top of your question says you're getting an error message while creating the table while the bottom part says you've already created the table. What's the exact error and is it at the time of table creation or insertion of records?

Comment: Always include error messages. I gave you an upvote because you were honest enough saying this is a homework task.

Comment: When the table is being checked to see if I created the table with the correct parameters it's telling me that I didn't. My school uses codio and it auto checks the table to see if it's correct and that is the error message I'm getting. [Error]: Create a 'classrooms' table with the requested structure. Reset the database and try again.

Comment: Maybe `course_id` is supposed to be a regular index instead of a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Is it probably failing on the FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES context?  You are trying to create a table that is EXPECTING the course_id to be found in a secondary table "college.courses".  If the college.courses table is not created yet, this table could never reference it.

Make sure the COURSES table is created FIRST

Comment: I did create the courses table first. I had to complete that and have it verified by codio before I could move on to this part.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE classrooms
(
id INT(3) unsigned primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
room_num INT(4) unsigned NOT NULL UNIQUE,
course_id INT(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES college.courses(id)
)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```